# Android AVD not displaying appropriate scale

Tags: screen, android-emulator, emulators, screen-resolution

How do I fix the display on my android AVD? The UI is completely out of whack. I'm using the following command line options to launch the AVD, but nothing I do within the 'scale' and 'dpi-device' options helps fix the messed up display (see example screenshot). I'm running on Arch Linux with the latest Nvidia proprietary driver 346.35. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Command:

```
$ emulator -verbose -scale 0.9 -dpi-device 480 -noaudio -no-boot-anim -noskin -no-snapshot @lollipop -qemu -m 1536 -enable-kvm
```

Also, according to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15244112/75314), I also did:

```
$ adb shell setprop qemu.sf.lcd_density 480
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell start
```

Doing this has made no difference to the messed up display on my emulator.

Note that I have to use the `-noskin` option because it refuses to  launch the emulator for me otherwise.

[image: AVD display 2]
[image: AVD display 1]

Answer (score 2):

I don't launch from the command line, but this question came up while I was trying to solve a similar problem.

I eventually solved it by replacing the `hw.lcd.density` value in the `.android/avd/<avd_name>.avd/config.ini` file with the value from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43860845/685777) nearest to the value in the skin's `hardware.ini` file (in my case that's at `<android-studio-location>/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/<skin-name>/hardware.ini`).

In my case, I'm emulating a Samsung Galaxy S6, and the Samsung provided skin has an `hw.lcd.density` of `200`, but the dimensions they provide are `1440x2560` and the provided background images are small, so they make the screen fit into a much smaller space (`474x839`), so the `config.ini` file has a `hw.lcd.density` value of `640`. Decreasing it to `213` and restarting the emulator fixes the problem (but I guess it doesn't quite accurately emulate the screen appearance. I don't know whether it's better than just using a different screen resolution value).